# How was the name "Ethereum" chosen?

Tags: history

How was the name "Ethereum" chosen? Is there a meaning or story behind it? Did Vitalik Buterin choose it or did someone else?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

source is a quote from vitalik buterin : [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/comment/3389/#Comment_3389)

> I was browsing a list of elements from science fiction on Wikipedia
>   when I came across the name. I immediately realized that I liked it
>   better than all of the other alternatives that I had seen; I suppose
>   it was the fact that sounded nice and it had the word "ether",
>   referring to the hypothetical invisible medium that permeates the
>   universe and allows light to travel.
>
> Although I did play wow back in the day, any reference to those level
>   70 baddies in Netherstorm is purely incidental.

Answer (score 3):

The name "Ethereum" has roots in ["the material supposed to fill the region of the universe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aether_(classical_element)) <s>and the computer game [World of Warcraft.](http://www.abelardschool.org/html/6a_vitalik.html)</s>

EDIT: @euri10 found the reference I tried to search for.